# Are webhooks retried if my server is down?

Tags: webhooks, branch.io

I have setup a webhook for install event. I would like to know what will happen if my site is down. Will the webhooks get retried incase of non 200 response codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question! Branch does not automatically retry webhooks in the case of a non 2xx response. However, Branch does allow you to go through and see every single time they have tried to fire a webhook. In the case of a non-2xx response, you would see a red 'X' next to the record. From there you can manually re-send said webhook to your server.

If this post does not resolve your issue(s) please ask more!